# Go about it another way

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

These sentences appear in Robert Heinlein's novel [Have Space Suit, Will Travel](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BG3SjVi5AvAC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=When+I+was+a+kid,+we+used+to+pretend+we+were+making+the+first+landing+on+the+Moon.+Then+I+gave+up+romantic+notions+and+realized+that+I+would+have+to+go+about+it+another+way.&source=bl&ots=ghps4ZBnaJ&sig=nBas3xQGq3xJk_0FMd6aEEJaa0M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tKS9U-HyK4ig7Aao4ICoCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=When%20I%20was%20a%20kid%2C%20we%20used%20to%20pretend%20we%20were%20making%20the%20first%20landing%20on%20the%20Moon.%20Then%20I%20gave%20up%20romantic%20notions%20and%20realized%20that%20I%20would%20have%20to%20go%20about%20it%20another%20way.&f=false):

> When I was a kid, we used to pretend we were making the first landing on the Moon. Then I gave up romantic notions and realized that I would have to ***go about it another way***.

What does ***go about it another way*** mean here?

Comment: 'Take a different approach' is another way of saying this if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I have to mention that you are reading some good books! You might want to check out *Podkayne of Mars* and *The moon is a harsh mistress*, though be careful with the second book there: it uses some non-standard English constructions.

As @EyeOfTheHawks mentioned "go about it another way" means to "take a different approach". In this case the problem is not exactly clear. The narrator (Kip, I think) is likely speaking about his path through life in general and saying that although landing on the Moon would be an exciting and romantic career, it is not realistic. He will need another path.

This is contrasting with the current circumstance: Kip just landed on the moon and can prove that he is not on Earth!

Comment: +1, and another if I could for the caveat on *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress*.

Answer (score 1):

**To go about something another way** means to try to do that thing in a different way because the current way is not working. It is to try a different approach, to try a different strategy.

The character in the book wanted to go to the Moon. That was his goal in life. When he was a kid, he used to pretend he was landing on the Moon. But that was just a game. At some point he realized that dreaming wasn't a realistic way to get to the Moon. He had to find a better way. He had **to go about it** [getting to the Moon] **another way**, a more realistic way.

Example:

Imagine someone is trying to catch a rabbit, and he is doing that by just chasing it, but this isn't working because the rabbit is too fast. He is going about it [catching the rabbit] the wrong way. He should go about it another way and set a trap or something.